# What does breach chance mean?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

On FTL, some weapons have a breach chance. What does breach do? How important is it?

Screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In FTL a Breach is a hole in the hull represented by a crack in the floor - you can see a hull breach in the room below the Engine room in the below screenshot

[image: Screenshot of a breach]

[image: Close up of breach]

Breaches slowly vent oxygen into space and also must be repaired *before* the system contained in that room can be repaired and so they can be particularly nasty when trying to repair vital systems in a room.

The breach chance of a weapon is the chance that the wepon will cause a hull breach in that room when it hits (I'm not sure what probability "low" corresponds to)

Answer (score 6):

Breaching creates a breach in the hull. Breaches will slowly remove oxygen from any room exposed to the breach (without an airlock between it and the breach).

Answer (score 6):

Other answers have covered the effect of breaches, slowly losing oxygen from a room. The wiki currently lists the [stats of all weapons](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Weapons/Tables), including the percentage for breach chance*

**Quick summary:**

"Breach Chance: Low" corresponds to a 10% to 30% chance
"Breach Chance: High" corresponds to a 80% to 100% chance

Interestingly, the Breach Missile, is the only weapon with "Breach Chance: High" that does not have a 100% chance of causing breaches.

**List of weapons with non-zero Breach Chance**

10% Breach Chance

- Leto Missile
- Artemis Missile
- Swarm Missile
- Crystal Burst Mark I
- Crystal Burst Mark II
- Heavy Crystal Mark I

20% Breach Chance

- Hermes Missile
- Pegasus Missile
- Hull Laser Mark I

30% Breach Chance

- Hull Missile
- Heavy Laser Mark I
- Heavy Laser Mark II
- Heavy Pierce Mark I
- Hull Laser Mark II

80% Breach Chance

- Breach Missile

100% Breach Chance

- Breach Bomb I
- Breach Bomb II
- Heavy Crystal Mark II

*Note: I double checked the game files, `FTL Faster Than Light\resources\data.dat`, to verify the wiki breach chance values. Under `weaponBlueprint` the `breachChance` field is always an integer between 0 and 10, and the values seem to match the wiki (e.g. Breach Missiles have a value of 8)